# Level of SQL Server in the messages window

Tags: sql-server

I have this message

> Msg 6603, Level 16, State 17, Line 38

in the result pane (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) of SQL Server Management Studio.

What does `Level 16` really mean? And where I can find the scale of the all these numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this article [Error Handling in SQL 2000 – a Background](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#severitylevels) or [a more up-to-date article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx).

Anything less than or equal to 10 is informational rather than an error.

Between 11 -16 there are various categories of user correctable errors (not the case that the higher the number the worse the error in this group)

Above 16 there are errors not corrigible by the user. Any error with severity 20 or above will terminate the connection.